# make rigid body end in a certain position

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

Is it possible to end a rigid body sim in a specific pose? I am trying to let a burger patty fall on a bun, but it does not want to reach the place where it belongs haha

Comment: you could bake the physics, then create a keyframe so that it ends up where you want?

Comment: i will try to, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could:

- Bake your physics to keyframes (header menu > *Object > Rigid Body > Bake to Keyframes*), parent the object to an empty, move the empty so that at the end it falls exactly where you want:

[image]

- Or bake the physics, then add a keyframe at the end to place it exactly where you want